# RedisSearch return same data irrespective of query

Tags: redis, redisearch, redisjson, redis-search

Search Query: `FT.search logIndex "@country:{Brazil}"` return 3 user_id timestamp country

Returned Values:

[image]

instead of country Brazil it is returning the data of China.

I did not find any solution to this problem or may be I am new to RediSearch.

Comment: Could you provide how you created your index, i.e. the call to FT.CREATE?

Also, inline text is easier that read than a linked image. You can make code look nicer by wrapping it with three backticks just like with Slack, Discord, and Markdown.

Comment: ft.create logIndex on json prefix 1 log schema $.user_id as user_id text sortable noindex $.timestamp as timestamp text sortable $.country as country tag sortable

Answer (score 1):

Does the record returned have multiple values for the country? If so, I am told that earlier dialects of RediSearch will only return the first one in the list even though it matched another value. You might want to try using `DIALECT 3` when you call `FT.SEARCH` and see if that helps.

Also, you can probably improve your schema:

```bash
FT.CREATE logIndex ON JSON PREFIX 1 log
  SCHEMA 
    $.user_id AS user_id TEXT SORTABLE NOINDEX
    $.timestamp AS timestamp TEXT SORTABLE
    $.country AS country TAG SORTABLE
```

I'm guessing `user_id` probably has values like `groyse`, `hchandani`, or `jamesz`. `TEXT` fields are for sentences and paragraphs of human-readable text. I'm guessing this would not describe a `user_id`. It might work better as a `TAG`.

If you convert `timestamp` to an UNIX Epoch datetime (in seconds), store it in your JSON as a number, and index it as `NUMERIC` then there are date functions when calling `FT.AGGREGATE` that you can take advantage of.

I would convert it to this:

```bash
FT.CREATE logIndex ON JSON PREFIX 1 log
  SCHEMA 
    $.user_id AS user_id TAG SORTABLE NOINDEX
    $.timestamp AS timestamp NUMERIC SORTABLE
    $.country AS country TAG SORTABLE
```

This doesn't solve your problem above, of course. It's just some extra unsolicited advice! ;)